# Running simple SELECT MS SQL Server query with JDBCTemplate using JTDS driver and c3p0 data source

Tags: spring, c3p0, jdbctemplate, jtds, mssql-jdbc

I am connecting to MS SQL server with following datasource

```
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" >
    <property name="driverClass" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:<port>" />
    <property name="user" value="${echo_db_user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${echo_db_password}" />
  </bean>

      <bean id="myProviderDAO" class="com.care.dao.impl.DataProviderImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
  </bean>


public class DataProviderImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport{
public Object runQuery(String staticQuery) {
    try {
        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(staticQuery);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
        return null;
    }
}
```

staticQuery is:

```
  Select
    sender,
        status_dt
    FROM
        ServiceTickets.dbo.trouble_ticket 
    WHERE
        status_dt BETWEEN '02-17-2010 07:00:00'  AND '04-30-2014 05:00:00'
```

When running this query I am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [

    Select
    sender,
        status_dt
    FROM
        ServiceTickets.dbo.trouble_ticket 
    WHERE
        status_dt BETWEEN '02-17-2010 07:00:00'  AND '04-30-2014 05:00:00'


                ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
```

1. Connection is happening as I have debugged the code and it passed where connection is retrieved.
2. Same query If I execute on Toad (client to ms sql server) executes properly.
3. I have used same set of steps to connect to Qracle DB and executing its queries and it works fine, only in case of MS SQL server I am facing this issue.

Comment: Why is there an Oracle specific error (ORA-00933) when you are actually using SQL Server?

Comment: @AndreiStefan :  gr8 catch, myProviderDAO spring injection was wrong.